# Nested recursive angular templates

Tags: templates, angularjs

Starting out in angular...

I have nested category/product tree:

```
var data = {
               "cats":[{
                   "name":"Cat 1",
                   "cats":[{
                       "name":"Cat 1-1",
                       "cats":[{
                           "name":"Cat 1-1-1",
                           "products":[{
                               "name":"Prod A",
                               "type":"class1"
                           },{
                               "name":"Prod K",
                               "type":"class2"
                           }]
                       },{
                           "name":"Cat 1-1-2",
                           "products":[{
                               "name":"Prod C",
                               "type":"class3"
                           },{
                               "name":"Prod F",
                               "type":"class3"
                           },{
                               "name":"Prod G",
                               "type":"class3"
                           }]
                       }]
                   },{
                       "name":"Cat 1-2",
                       "cats":[{
                           "name":"Cat 1-2-1",
                           "products":[{
                               "name":"Prod G",
                               "type":"class3"
                           }]
                       },{
                           "name":"Cat 1-2-2",
                           "products":[{
                               "name":"Prod J",
                               "type":"class2"
                           },{
                               "name":"Prod L",
                               "type":"class3"
                           }]
                       }]
                   }]
               },{
                  ...
               }]
           }
```

I need to display this in nested list like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>Cat 1
    <ul>
        <li>Cat 1-1
        <ul>
            <li>Cat 1-1-1
            <ul>
                <li class="class1">Prod A</li>
                <li class="class2">Prod K</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Cat 1-1-2
            <ul>
                <li class="class3">Prod C</li>
                <li class="class3">Prod F</li>
                <li class="class3">Prod G</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Cat 1-2
        <ul>
            <li>Cat 1-2-1
            <ul>
                <li class="class3">Prod G</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Cat 1-2-2
            <ul>
                <li class="class2">Prod J</li>
                <li class="class3">Prod L</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

so far I have:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="cat-tmpl">
    {{ section.name }}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-include="'cat-tmpl'"></li>
        <li ng-repeat="product in products" ng-include="'product-tmpl'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template"  id="product-tmpl">
    {{product.name}}
</script>
<div ng-controller="menuCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-include="'cat-tmpl'"></li>
        <li ng-repeat="product in products" ng-include="'product-tmpl'"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and

```
var menuApp = angular.module('menuApp', []);

menuApp.controller('menuCtrl', function menuCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('/ajax/getmenu').success(function(data) {
    $scope.sections = data;
});
});
```

the async request gets the data as described in the json obj above...

the result of this however is each cat and product being nested regardless. eg

```
<ul>
    <li>Cat 1
    <ul>
        <li>Cat 1-1
        <ul>
            <li>Cat 1-1-1
            <ul>
                <li>Prod A
                <ul>
                    <li>Prod K
                    <ul>
                        <li>Cat 1-1-2
                        ...
```

Any tips here much appreciated - as normal once the penny drops I'm usually ok - its just not dropping at the mo.

Comment: try this  http://jsbin.com/acibiv/3/edit

Comment: cheers dude - a little playing around and I figured out how to implement the different templates I required - you are star.

Comment: @charlietfl, place it as an answer please. It is amazing!

Comment: @RadimKöhler I can't take credit..it came from here  http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/

Comment: @charlietfl I see. Thanks for sharing. Amazing. thanks *(unbelievable how difficult stuff I can produce... while someone else...)*

Answer (score 0):

here's an example that does pretty much the same thing:

http://jsbin.com/hokupe/1/edit

I wrote a blog post and created a 10-15 minutes video on how it was implemented:

http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/07/15/angularjs-using-templates-ng-include-create-infinite-tree/

Sample Code:

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="treeLevel.html">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="checkbox"
          name="itemSelection"
          ng-model="item._Selected" />
        {{item.text}}
        <div ng-include=" 'treeLevel.html'"
            onload="items = item.children">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </script>
  <div ng-include=" 'treeLevel.html' "
       onload="items = sourceItems">
  </div>
```